# Parsing the text file in js

Tags: javascript, parsing

I want to parse the text which has the following structure;

```
name=Rachel
surname=Chung
age=21
```

after parsing i want to get;

```
name=
surname=
age=
```

at first i split it by new lines and i get,

```
name=Rachelsurname=Chungage=21
```

It is not a good idea because now it's more complicated to get the first key values. 
I also try to split according to the "=" charachter but then I got;

```
 name,Rachelsurname,Chungage,21
```

Can you suggest me anything to get the keys from such a text file?

Comment: split by newlines, you should get an ARRAY of lines, split each by `=`, and output the first element and an = ... when you say after parsing you want to "get" ... in what form? a string? an array? output to console? to a web page?

Comment: @JaromandaX Sir, I guess provided input will be invalid string..Refer this: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/1dd8qfoq/

Comment: I simply do not understand what you are sayin

Comment: @RayonDabre multiline strings need to be escaped https://jsfiddle.net/3718y666/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var result = yourFileData.match(/^.+=/gm).join('\r\n')
```

Comment: Omg. It's working. Can you please tell me the logic? I've never understand the expression :D

Comment: Match function finds substrings by given pattern (`/^.+=/gm`) called regual expression. Characters `/` and `/` are beggining and endind of pattern, `gm` are modifiers. Expression `^.+=` means: find substring from beggining of line (`^`), substring might be letter or number (`.`) and length of substring must be one or more symbols (`+`) and symbol `=` comes after substring (`=`). Modifier `g` - find all matches (by default it finds only first occurence), `m` - input string is multi-line. Fuction returns array `['name=', 'surname=', 'age=']` of matched substrings, which joined by new line `\r\n`

Comment: Sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're `reading files` I'm assuming you're working with Node.

There is a nice module to read files line by line, called as `readline`

First

`npm install readline`

Then

```
var readline = require('readline');
var path = 'path/to/your/text/file.txt';

var readStream = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(path),
    output: process.stdout,
    terminal: false
});


var keys = [];
var values = [];
readStream.on('line', function(line) {
    var l = line.split('=');
    keys.push(l[0]);
    values.push(l[1]);
});

readStream.on('close', function() {
    console.log(keys);
    console.log(values);
});
```